# trailhead module-----Create an Apex class that returns contacts based on incoming parameters

Tags: trailhead

```
public class ContactSearch {
    public static list<contact> searchForContacts(string lastname,string MailingPostalCode)
    { 
        list<contact>ContactList=[select id,name,lastname,mailingpostalcode from contact where lastname=:'lastname' and mailingpostalcode=:'MailingPostalcode'];
        return contactlist;
    }
}
```

error thrown====>

> Challenge not yet complete in venkat@gynanvruksh.com Executing the
>   'searchForContacts' method failed. Either the method does not exist,
>   is not static, or does not return the expected contacts.

Comment: Can you post the link of the trailhead module

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you have passed to the method are not getting utilized in the logic of the method. In below line of code, You have passed the value as a static string in where clause of your query and not as a variable.

```
list<contact> ContactList=[select id,name,lastname,mailingpostalcode from contact where lastname=:'lastname' and mailingpostalcode=:'MailingPostalcode'];
```

Instead you need to remove the single quotes from lastname and mailingpostalcode in where clause and it will solve your problem.

```
list<contact> ContactList=[select id,name,lastname,mailingpostalcode from contact where lastname=:lastname and mailingpostalcode=:MailingPostalcode];
```

You should know about using a bind variable in soql query.

> SOQL and SOSL statements in Apex can reference Apex code variables and
>   expressions if they’re preceded by a colon (:). This use of a local
>   code variable within a SOQL or SOSL statement is called a bind. The
>   Apex parser first evaluates the local variable in code context before
>   executing the SOQL or SOSL statement.

Read more about it here:- [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm?search_text=bind%20variables)